# Module '"redis"' has no exported member 'RedisClient'

Tags: express, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I am creating a multi-node Express/Socket.io server using Typescript and I am trying to import RedisClient from redis, but I can't get it to work because I get the error

> Module '"redis"' has no exported member 'RedisClient'

It seems to be trying to retrieve it form

> node_modules/redis/dist/index

But in reality it is here:

> node_modules/@types/redis"

How can I get it to import from the right place?

Comment: I ended up copying the contents of the file in "node_modules/@types/redis" and pasting them at the end of the file in "node_modules/redis/dist/index". That made the problem go away, but I am sure this can't be sustainable solution. I hope there is a better solution to this out there.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Redis package has been officially updated to v4 recently, which introduced some [breaking changes](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/v3-to-v4.md), including several interface changes.

I recommend to temporarily use the v3 until all your dependencies (including @types/redis) are properly updated:

```
npm install redis@3
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking for some time I realized that things changed and the documentation states that you now do NOT need to use RedisClient. You now need to use:

```
import { createClient } from "redis";
```

This is what things look like now:

```
const pubClient = createClient({ url: `redis://<path to redis>:6379` });
```